# WSL - ssh shortcuts like in putty

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Putty, we can store "Saved Sessions" which are essentially shortcuts for ssh connections.

I typically use mtPutty which provides a quick drop down where i can quickly click on an item to connect to that host.

[image]

Is there anything like this at all on linux/WSL?

I know in the terminal I can create "shortcuts" in an ~/.ssh/config file but i'm referring more to a gui where i can easily click and connect.

Comment: i'm not sshing into wsl. i'm wanting to ssh from wsl to remote machines but using a point click type interface ala putty saved sessions instead of typing

Comment: no. the solution you provided is not what i was looking for. please reread my post above.

Comment: You could create multiple Windows Shortcuts with command "wsl.exe ssh username@domain.com@servertoconnectto". Then for a nice UI, put all of the shortcuts in a folder and make a Toolbar out of it on your Taskbar. (Right click Taskbar -> Toolbars...New toolbar...). Only big con is that it will prompt for passwords.